# How to dynamically create a ag- grid IServerSideGetRowsRequest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am implementing a serverside export excel feature. I want to create an object of type IServerSideGetRowsRequest dynamically on click based on the current state of the grid when user presses the export excel button.

```
const columnState = columnApi.getColumnState();

const sortModel = columnState.filter((col) => col.sort);

return {
  startRow: 0,
  endRow: 1000,
  rowGroupCols: [],
  valueCols: columnApi.getValueColumns(),
  pivotCols: columnApi.getPivotColumns(),
  pivotMode: columnApi.isPivotMode(),
  groupKeys: [],
  filterModel: gridApi.getFilterModel(),
  sortModel: sortModel,
};
```

}
I have tried this code so far but i am met with type issues :

1. Type 'Column[]' is not assignable to type 'ColumnVO[]'.
2. Type 'ColumnState[]' is not assignable to type 'SortModelItem[]'.

is there any api which can directly get me the object instead of me having to create it ?